# Can anyone compile gVIM source code with a change

Tags: vim

I'm at Windows and i'm having trouble to compile Vim source code.

Can any one recompile it without this ugly (3d) border?

[image]

It is located at the file `src/gui_w32.c`. At line `1476`, change `WS_EX_CLIENTEDGE` flag to `0`:

```
s_textArea = CreateWindowEx(
    WS_EX_CLIENTEDGE,
    szTextAreaClass, "Vim text area",
    WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE, 0, 0,
    100,                /* Any value will do for now */
    100,                /* Any value will do for now */
    s_hwnd, NULL,
    s_hinst, NULL);
```

I think that will solve.

**[edit]**

Mutch better, ahh

[image]

Comment: Feel free to post the error message you get and get help about that. Stack Overflow is a place to ask questions, not a place to get things done.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By asking strangers on the Internet to compile a binary for you, you'll be

- opening yourself up for malicious code; you'll never know what other modifications may have been done to the source code
- stuck with that special build for a long time, while Vim development progresses.

Therefore, it would be much better to ask about the particular problem you're having with the dev environment, compiler, etc.

Additionally, if you think that the UI should be improved in general, please submit your patch to the [vim_dev mailing list](http://www.vim.org/community.php). (In my GVIM, the border is there, but it's not so pronounced as in your screenshot, and I quite like it that way.)

Comment: Nice warnings, although i dont care about first one.

Comment: Let's talk again after I've sent you a `gvim.exe` that erases your hard disk (or even more evil, silently changes a single character in some of your edited files).

Comment: i forgot i can change the binary info. So i did it. Check my update.